# OKHTTP Post FormDataMultiPart

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data, okhttp

I need your help, i'd like to know if there is a way to post a FormDataMultiPart with okHttp.

I know you're gonna say that there already are responses.

This is my case :

// Resource

```
@Consume(FORMDATAMULTIPART)
public Response getMultiPart(FormDataMultiPart multipart) {
   return response.ok(service.postMultiPart(multipart);
}
```

// Service

```
public void postMultiPart(FormDataMultiPart multiPart) {
   OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
   final Request request = new Request.Builder() {
      .url(URL)
      .post(multiPart)
}
```

I know that post only get RequestBody and this is my question, do you know guys a way to convert the FormDataMultiPart to RequestBody??

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In the **Service** change this part of the code

```
final Request request = new Request.Builder() {
      .url(URL)
      .post(multiPart)
```

to (*assuming i'm sending a file*) and use **RequestBuilder**

```
File file; // This is the file I want to send.
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data");
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM).addFormDataPart("key", "name", RequestBody.create(mediaType, file)).build();

okhttp3.Request.Builder requestBuilder = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                    .headers(headerBuild)
                    .url(url);
requestBuilder.post(requestBody);
okhttp3.Request request = requestBuilder.build();
```

Have a look at MediaType which has been added in the above code.